# Best way to copy bits from a signed to an unsigned variable of same size in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, memory-safety

In C++ or C I'd either use memcpy or use pointers like this:

```
uint16_t b = NULL;
int16_t signed_val = -50;
uint16_t b = *(int16_t*)&signed_val;
```

I know C# supports pointers, but I'm trying to avoid using them in this case. I can't figure out a more sensible solution.

Comment: `ushort b = (ushort)signedVal`? Exactly the same as I'd use in C -- your pointer-casting is UB in C I think, but a direct cast is defined and safe

Comment: Doesn't casting it change the bit-pattern? I don't want it to convert a negative number to a positive one within the signed bounds. I want it to think it's a very large number instead.

Comment: Not when the bit size is identical. Where things are unexpected is when you start doing bitwise operators on values smaller than 32-bit because it *does* convert up to 32-bit and you have to cast where it doesn't look like it should be necessary.

Comment: @canton7 maybe add an unchecked: `ushort b = unchecked((ushort)signedVal)` to avoid overflow exception in case the CheckForOverflowUnderflow compiler option is set.

Comment: I can't edit the comment any more, but yes, adding `unchecked` is a good idea. If you follow the specification for that cast through, you'll find it results in keeping the same bit pattern in both C# and C (assuming C is using 2's complement, which isn't guaranteed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the simple way?

```
short signed_val = -50;
ushort unsigned_val = (ushort)signed_val;
```

unsigned_val = 65486

Comment: You need `unchecked` context for this to work, so `unchecked((ushort)signed_val)`

Comment: @Charlieface Only if checked arithmetic is enabled, which is very rare

Comment: @canton7 True, but when it makes a difference to correctness it's sensible to put it in, because you never know when someone will just change it project-wide.